# Convert image to Blob

Tags: image, canvas, blob

I want to upload image data to a php script on the server. I have a URL for an image source (PNG, the image might be located on a different server). I load this into a Javascript image, draw this into a canvas and use the [canvas.toBlob()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob) method (or a polyfill as it is not mainly supported yet) to generate a blob holding the image data. This works fine, but I recognized that the resulting blob size is much bigger than the original image data.
In contrast if I use a HTML File input and let the user select an image on the client the resulting blob has equal size to the original image. Can I get image data from a canvas that is equal to the original image size?

I guess the reason is that I loose the PNG (or any image compression) when using the canvas.toBlob() polyfill:

```
value: function (callback, type, quality) {

    var binStr = atob(this.toDataURL(type, quality).split(',')[1]),
        len = binStr.length,
        arr = new Uint8Array(len);

    for (var i=0; i<len; i++ ) {
        arr[i] = binStr.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    callback(new Blob([arr], {type: type || 'image/png'}));
}
```

I am confused by so many conversion steps via image, canvas, blob - so maybe there is an alternative to get the image data from a given URL and finally append it to FormData to send it to the server?

Comment: Is the server manipulating the image data? If you just want your image stored in blob format then specify a blob-type column in your DB and insert a `context.toDataURL` submitted by the client.

Comment: from my experience when you convert the bytes from an image to a blob/dataUrl you increase the size of the object my about 30%

Comment: @markE There is no database involved, the question is just about how to get the image data from image and sent to the server without increasing it too much.

Comment: @QBM5 My original image is 24KB and the resulting data blob holds 1.9MB - it is really high increase here.

Comment: yeah, something else is going on there

Comment: Yep, blobs are fatter than compressed image formats. A workaround: 1. Install NodeJS on the server, 2. Submit `context.toDataURL` (use 'image/jpeg' for smaller submission), 3. Create an imageobject from the dataURL, 4. `drawImage` the imageobject, 5. `getImageData` to get the image data.

Comment: @markE, à blob of a file should be the same size as the file, and certainly not 1000 times larger. As QMB5 says there must be something else (resizing of the image?) and that would be great if OP gave us more info.

Comment: A true alternative to avoid so much steps is to use xhr with the responseType = "blob".

Comment: @Kaiido. Sure, the OP's blob-to-img ratio is off the charts -- something's wrong there. But the blob will still be larger than a png. If transfer size/time is still critical after fixing the "oops" then they could send a quality-modified jpeg and extract the imageData on the server.

Comment: But actually I don't get why OP doesn't simply download the image server side and just send the URL as a string...

Comment: @Kaiido. We have precious little code to chew on an no use-case to limit our wandering imaginations ...

Comment: @QBM5 Sry guys you are right, I just confused two images. The image I expected was much smaller than the one actually being set in my URL query. A further problem was that I got a JPG file and rendered it via canvas to PNG what did a quite dramatic increase of image data, of course. Now I got the normal increase of size of about 30%.

Comment: @Kaiido So you mean I could just pass the image URL to the server, than download it server side and use the image data as needed? At the moment I am doing a two steps approach by downloading it to the client and uploading it to the destination server and it would be nice if I could leave out the first step here with your suggestion.

Comment: @Michbeckable, you didn't told us why you need this data for, but there are a few ways to request a file server-side (in php you could use curl or file_get_contents ). This would even avoid some client side restrictions (CORS) but would also imply to do some security checks. I'm not a server side specialist so the best would be for you to read a bit about those possibilities and then ask a new question with proper tags.

Comment: @Michbeckable. You can send (for example) a `.toDataURL()` to the server. If you have NodeJS loaded on the server you can `drawImage` an image object (created from the .toDataURL) onto a server-side canvas. Then `.getImageData` to fetch your desired image pixel data. NodeJS is a server-side implementation of JavaScript+Basic HTML elements -- very useful to have this capability on the server!

Comment: @markE I don't think OP is talking about an image ImageData object. He is sending the full compressed file data (toDataURL() ) as a blob. But if using nodejs there are also ways to fetch data from external urls

Comment: @Kaiido. I have no idea what the OP is trying to achieve and he doesn't present his use-case so I'm onto other things :-//

Comment: @markE I did not present my use-case as I wanted to focus my problem on the image size increasing dramatically. Actually I need to copy the image file from some location (might be cross origin) to my server. As I did not know how to copy it server-side when it is from different origin I tried this way involving the client and drawing it to canvas to get the blob. I will try the solution as suggested and try directly from server side with CURL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `toDataURL` when using the png format only uses a limited set of the possible formats available for PNG files. It is the 8bit per channel RGBA (32 bits) compressed format. There are no options to use any of the other formats available so you are forced to include redundant data when you save as a PNG. PNG also has a 24bit and 8 bit format. PNG also has several compression options available though I am unsure which is used but each browser.

In most cases it is best to send the original image. If you need to modify the image and do not use the alpha channel (no transparency) but still want the quality to be high send it as a jpeg with quality set to 1 (max).

You may also consider the use of a custom encoder for PNG that gives you access to more of the PNG encoding options, or even try one of the many other formats available, or make up your own format, though you will be hard pushed to improve on jpeg and webp.

You could also consider compressing the data on the server when you store it, even jpeg and webp have a little room for more compression. For transport you should not worry as most data these days is compressed as it leaves the page and most definitely compressed by the time it leaves the clients ISP

Comment: Actually I had a confusion in my use case, so the size increase of image appeared to be so dramatic. I vote up your answer for providing useful information on this topic anyway.

Comment: Just wanted to drop in and say that in the meantime `<canvas>` got a [`toBlob()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob) method that might be helpful.